# Ubuntu minimal desktop installation on ubuntu server fails

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

I have a Raspberry PI running ubuntu server 22.04. Now I wanted to install a desktop environment with the following command:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop-minimal
```

But then I get these errors:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/x/xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu/xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu_22.0.0-1build1_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/x/xserver-xorg-video-ati/xserver-xorg-video-radeon_19.1.0-2build3_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/x/xserver-xorg-video-ati/xserver-xorg-video-ati_19.1.0-2build3_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/x/xserver-xorg-video-fbdev/xserver-xorg-video-fbdev_0.5.0-2build1_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/x/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/xserver-xorg-video-nouveau_1.0.17-2build1_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/x/xserver-xorg-video-vesa/xserver-xorg-video-vesa_2.5.0-1build4_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/x/xorg/xserver-xorg-video-all_7.7%2b23ubuntu2_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/y/yaru-theme/yaru-theme-gtk_22.04.4_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/y/yaru-theme/yaru-theme-icon_22.04.4_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/y/yaru-theme/yaru-theme-sound_22.04.4_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/b/brltty/brltty_6.4-4ubuntu2_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/c/cups/cups-bsd_2.4.1op1-1ubuntu4_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/c/cups-pk-helper/cups-pk-helper_0.2.6-1ubuntu5_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/f/fprintd/fprintd_1.94.2-1_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/liba/libauthen-sasl-perl/libauthen-sasl-perl_2.1600-1.1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/d/ding-libs/libbasicobjects0_0.6.2-1_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/c/c-ares/libc-ares2_1.18.1-1build1_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-dbg_2.35-0ubuntu3_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/libc/libcanberra/libcanberra-gtk3-module_0.30-10ubuntu1_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/d/ding-libs/libcollection4_0.6.2-1_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/d/ding-libs/libdhash1_0.6.2-1_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/d/ding-libs/libpath-utils1_0.6.2-1_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/d/ding-libs/libref-array1_0.6.2-1_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/d/ding-libs/libini-config5_0.6.2-1_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/s/sssd/libipa-hbac0_2.6.3-1ubuntu3_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/libl/liblouisutdml/liblouisutdml-bin_2.10.0-4_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/s/sssd/libnss-sss_2.6.3-1ubuntu3_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/f/fprintd/libpam-fprintd_1.94.2-1_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/s/sssd/libpam-sss_2.6.3-1ubuntu3_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/r/rygel/librygel-core-2.6-2_0.40.3-1ubuntu2_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/r/rygel/librygel-db-2.6-2_0.40.3-1ubuntu2_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/r/rygel/librygel-renderer-2.6-2_0.40.3-1ubuntu2_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/r/rygel/librygel-server-2.6-2_0.40.3-1ubuntu2_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/s/sbc/libsbc1_1.5-3build2_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/s/sssd/libsss-certmap0_2.6.3-1ubuntu3_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/s/sssd/libsss-idmap0_2.6.3-1ubuntu3_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/s/sssd/libsss-nss-idmap0_2.6.3-1ubuntu3_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/m/mobile-broadband-provider-info/mobile-broadband-provider-info_20220315-1_all.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/p/pulseaudio/pulseaudio-module-bluetooth_15.99.1%2bdfsg1-1ubuntu1_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/s/sssd/python3-sss_2.6.3-1ubuntu3_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/r/rygel/rygel_0.40.3-1ubuntu2_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/s/sssd/sssd-common_2.6.3-1ubuntu3_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/s/sssd/sssd-ad-common_2.6.3-1ubuntu3_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/s/sssd/sssd-krb5-common_2.6.3-1ubuntu3_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/s/sssd/sssd-ad_2.6.3-1ubuntu3_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/s/sssd/sssd-ipa_2.6.3-1ubuntu3_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/s/sssd/sssd-krb5_2.6.3-1ubuntu3_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/s/sssd/sssd-ldap_2.6.3-1ubuntu3_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/s/sssd/sssd-proxy_2.6.3-1ubuntu3_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/s/sssd/sssd_2.6.3-1ubuntu3_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/b/brltty/xbrlapi_6.4-4ubuntu2_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/x/xorg-server/xserver-xorg-legacy_21.1.3-2ubuntu2_arm64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

What do I wrong and how can I fix these errors?

Comment: I would suggest asking on the ubuntu forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `sudo apt-get update`. This will download the repository package lists and update them to reflect the latest versions.